# Inscribed and circumscribed circle have the same midpoint

Tags: geometry, contest-math

$"$Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $\sphericalangle ACB=90°$. Let $H$ be the intersection of the line segment $AB$ and the height $h$ with respect to $C.$ Furthermore, let $P$ and $Q$ be the intersection of the line segment $AB$ and the angle bisectors of the angles $\sphericalangle ACH$ and $\sphericalangle HCB$.
Show that the centre of the circumscribed circle of $PQC$ is the same as the centre of the inscribed circle of $ABC."$
I'm really helpless with this problem, appreciate all your help.

Just a quick sketch. $M$ is the centre of both circles:
[image: Just a quick sketch. M is the centre of both circles]

Here are my thoughts so far (thanks for the comment pointing this out):
The way I see it, there are two different ways to approach this; either assume that the inscribed circle is given and try to show that it is concentric to the circumscribed circle of the inner triangle. This could be done either by showing that the perpendicular line segment bisector intersects in $M$ or that the distance between $M$ and $P$ is the same as between $M$ and $Q$ and $M$ and $C.$
You could also try the other way around.
My main problem is, that I am a rookie at elementary geometry and have no experience in proofs for that matter.

Comment: "the midpoint of the [...] circle", do you mean the centre of that circle?

Comment: Is it in 3d spherical geometry?

Comment: yes, that is what I meant, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Narasimham no, 2D Geometry only

Comment: Can you draw a diagram?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What do you know about heights? About bisectors? Similar triangles?

Comment: @jjagmath I am aware that the height divides the triangle into two triangles that are both similar to the original triangle. The bisectors of a triangle intersect in the centre of the circumscribed circle. Can you give me a hint maybe? thank you

Comment: @tigrawr Assume that $M$ is the circumcircle of $\Delta CPQ$, note that $\angle PMQ = 2 \times \angle PCQ$. Then prove that $M$ is the in-center of $\Delta ABC$ by showing that $CM$ bisects $\angle ACB$ and $AM$ bisects $\angle BAC$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your picture, let's assume $M$ is the center of the circumscribed circle of $PCQ$.

Now consider the line segment $MC$.

We first show that $MC$ is the bisector. Notice that:

$$\angle HCA=90^{\circ}-\angle A \implies \angle PCA=\angle HCP=\angle 45^{\circ}-\angle \frac{A}{2}\implies \angle HPC= 45^{\circ}+\angle \frac{A}{2};$$

hence: $\angle QCM=90^{\circ}-\angle QPC=45^{\circ}-\angle \frac{A}{2}$ (because we assumed $M$ is the center of the circumscribed circle). As a result, we have: $\angle QCM=\angle PCA$.

Now, realize that $\angle QCP=45^{\circ}$. Therefore:

$$45^{\circ}= \angle QCP=\angle QCM +\angle MCP=\angle PCA +\angle MCP=\angle MCA\implies \angle MCA=45^{\circ}.$$

Since we assumed $M$ is the center of the circumscribed circle and $\angle QCP=45^{\circ}$, we easily conclude $\angle AQM=45^{\circ}$. By using the law of sine in $AQM$ and $AMC$, we get:

$$\frac {\sin \angle QAM}{\sin 45^{\circ}}=\frac {QM}{AM}=\frac {MC}{AM}=\frac {\sin \angle MAC}{\sin 45^{\circ}};$$

hence $\angle QAM=\angle MAC$ (simply because $\angle A<90^{\circ}$), which means $AM$ is the bisector as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get it now